# long label of \textfield with a break?

Tags: hyperref, forms

i am working on a tex-file that looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 
\renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofTextMultiline}{6\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{\makebox[3.5cm][l]{#1: }%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\raisebox{-\height}{#2}}}
\def\LayoutChoiceField#1#2{\makebox[6em][l]{#1: }#2}
\newdimen\longline
\longline=\textwidth\advance\longline-6em

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\TextField[name=Beschreibung,multiline=true,height=8\baselineskip,
width=\longline,borderwidth=0,backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}]
{\textbf{foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar }}\vskip2ex
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the foobar text doesn't align on the left side, but instead goes under the textfield. I tried to use a break, but this doesn't work. I'd be glad if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  am not sure that I understand what output you want, but perhaps you mean

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 
\renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofTextMultiline}{6\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{\makebox[3.5cm][l]{#1: }%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\raisebox{-\height}{#2}}}
\def\LayoutChoiceField#1#2{\makebox[6em][l]{#1: }#2}
\newdimen\longline
\longline=\textwidth\advance\longline-6em

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\TextField[name=Beschreibung,multiline=true,height=8\baselineskip,
width=\longline,borderwidth=0,backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}]
{\textbf{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedleft foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar}}}%
\vspace{2ex}%
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```